# Add an element to an array of structs and merge the arrays of structs in Spark 2.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've the below dataframe schema as df.currentSchema and need to obtain the expectedSchema as df.expectedSchema, is there a way i can achieve this in Spark 2.3

df.currentSchema:

```
 |-- enqueuedTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- VIN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TT: long (nullable = true)
 |-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ADA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
 |-- ADW: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
```

df.expectedSchema:

```
 |-- enqueuedTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- VIN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TT: long (nullable = true)
 |-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SIGNAL: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- SN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- E:  long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V:  double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SN: string (nullable = true) 
 |    |    |-- E:  long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V:  double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- SN: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
```

Sample data:

```
 +----------------+---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|vin              |tt |msg_type |ada                                                  |adw                       |                      |
+-----------------+---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
|FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":2, {"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":1}]      |null                      |                          
|FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |null                                                 |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":3}]  |                      
|FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |null                                                 |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":4.1}]|
+-----------------+---+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Note: Two things need to be achieved here:

1. New field SN to be created for each E, V pair within the element and it's value should be a array name. ex: For the first array column(ADA), the value of SN = ADA.
2. Merge the arrays(ADA, ADW) into one single outer array(SIGNAL).

Comment: The schema that you are expecting is incorrect and will failed while you will try to access  SIGNAL.SN since there are multiple column with same name under SIGNAL.

Answer (score 0):

The schema you are looking is incorrect & might fail while you are writing the dataframe. 
I tweaked the schema as below:

```
scala> newDF.printSchema
root
 |-- ADA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ADW: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sig: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- SN: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SN: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
```

If you are fine with this schema, please read further in achieving it.

Created dummy data to replicate your schema (this step can be ignored)

```
scala> val vas = """{"df":[ { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }, { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }, { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW":[{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }] }"""
vas: String = {"df":[ { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }, { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }, { "vin": "FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "tt": 0, "MSG_TYPE": "SIGNAL", "number": 123, "ADA": [{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}], "ADW":[{"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":2}, {"E":"15XXXXXXXX","V":1}] }] }

scala> val df = spark.read.json(Seq(vas).toDS).toDF.withColumn("arr", explode($"df")).select("arr.*")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ADA: array<struct<E:string,V:bigint>>, ADW: array<struct<E:string,V:bigint>> ... 4 more fields]
```

I hope this is how your data looks like:

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+------+---+-----------------+
|ADA                             |ADW                             |MSG_TYPE|number|tt |vin              |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+------+---+-----------------+
|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|SIGNAL  |123   |0  |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|SIGNAL  |123   |0  |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|[[15XXXXXXXX,2], [15XXXXXXXX,1]]|SIGNAL  |123   |0  |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+--------+------+---+-----------------+
```

Step to achieve the required output

```
scala> val newDF = df.withColumn("sig", struct($"ADA".as("SN"), $"ADW".as("SN")))
newDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ADA: array<struct<E:string,V:bigint>>, ADW: array<struct<E:string,V:bigint>> ... 5 more fields]

scala> newDF.printSchema
root
 |-- ADA: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ADW: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tt: long (nullable = true)
 |-- vin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sig: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- SN: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SN: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- E: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- V: long (nullable = true)
```

I tried to write this dataframe & it is working fine

```
newDF.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path + "newDF.parquet")
```

Comment: Hello @Nikk, is there a way i can use  arrays_zip in Spark 2.3, i read arrays_zip has been introduced in Spark 2.4.  something like below should work for me.                                                                                      val mod_df = newDF.withColumn("SIGNAL_TEST",
      arrays_zip(
        array(lit("ABS")).as("SN"),
        col("ABS.E").as("E"),
        col("ABS.V").alias("V")
      )).withColumn("SIGNAL",
        $"SIGNAL_TEST".cast(ArrayType(elem_struct_recomposed)))

Comment: Hi @AnilKumarKB, hope you are asking me. If you want to ask Nikk, better to reply to the above comment rather than comment here. But anyway, let me give my inputs, didn't come over array_zip function, but based on your update you may need to cast the datatype. If you use my method, datatypes are inferred by default.

Comment: Hello @Sarath, I would need the data as shown in the final_output_data to be, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316820/add-column-name-as-a-new-element-to-array-of-structs-using-spark-2-3