# Add column name as a new element to array of structs using Spark 2.3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've my current.printSchema as shown below and the sample JSON data is as shown where the columns(ada, adw) are of type array(struct).

```
    root
    |-- VIN: string (nullable = true)
    |-- TT: long (nullable = true)
    |-- MSG_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
    |-- ABS: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
    |-- ADA: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)
    |-- ADW: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
    |    |    |-- E: long (nullable = true)
    |    |    |-- V: double (nullable = true)

    current_data:
               +---------------- +---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+
               |vin              |tt |msg_type |ada                                                  |adw                       |                      
               +-----------------+---+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+
               |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":2, {"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":1}]      |null                      |                          
               |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |null                                                 |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":3}]  |                      
               |FU7XXXXXXXXXXXXXX|0  |SIGNAL   |null                                                 |[{"E":15XXXXXXXX,"V":4.1}]|
               +-----------------+---+---------+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I would need final_output_data as show below, where the array(struct) columns(ada, adw) should be appended within the struct as an additional element and there should be an outer column called event.

```
  final_output_data to be:
```

[image]

so that i can use explode function as shown below to get the required output:

```
 SELECT vin, tt, msg_type, events.SN as SN, events.E as ST,events.V as SV FROM table_name LATERAL VIEW explode(event) exploded_table as events;
```

I seen in Spark 2.4 we could use arrays_zip function as show below, but is there a way i can achieve this using Spark 2.3 either through UDF, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    val mod_df = df.withColumn("SIGNAL_TEST", 
    arrays_zip(
        array(lit("ABS")).as("SN"),
        col("ABS.E").as("E"),
        col("ABS.V").alias("V")
                ))
.withColumn("SIGNAL", 
           $"SIGNAL_TEST".cast(ArrayType(elem_struct_recomposed)))
```